# How can I carrier unlock my windows phone device?

Tags: unlocking

If you have carrier unlocked (not developer unlock) a Windows Phone, how did you do it and how long after the phone's release were you able to do it. I have succesfully carrier unlocked an htc Surround and a Samsung Focus, but I'm still trying to unlock my htc Titan.

Comment: I chose to use a 3rd party vendor to get the unlock code. It seems they had more information about my device than the carrier or the maunfacturer O.o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick to unlocking a Windows Phone is:

1. Have the correct unlock code. You need to know your IMEI number to obtain one.  Entering `*#06#` in the dialler will bring it up. Sometimes a carrier will provide the code for free.  It doesn't hurt to ask before buying one online.
2. Insert a SIM card from a different carrier, in order to get the PIN prompt to appear.

I was able to easily get an unlock code for under $5 on eBay (> 1 year after release). I like to use eBay to get unlock codes because the seller feedback will usually provide a good indication of how legit their service is.

Comment: This is exactly how I unlocked my other devices, AT&T gave me the unlock code just by asking nicely... however AT&T is holding onto the Titan with a deathgrip =p  I called htc's engineering team and got to talk to some of the guys over there. They actually ship the unlock for each device to the carrier and the carrier puts it into a database. It comes down to how long the device has been out on the market and it seems 1 year is the gold standard. Thank everyone who answered!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how acceptable you will find this answer, but I have seen a few [ads](http://cellphoneforums.net/htc/t335680-how-unlock-htc-titan-unlock-code-any-gsm-network.html) around the internet offering the unlock code. Here is a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLtBalMVJDA) showing it in action.

Basically, you get enter your IME number at http://www.cellunlocker.net/, and it will give you an unlock code along with instructions on how to do it. I haven't looked into the site, but if it is legit Maybe it will be what you need.

Comment: This seems to work although the cost for me would have been $29.99, so I'm looking into other options.

Answer (score 2):

I've unlocked a Windows Phone before (LG Optimus 7 E900h in Telcel, Mexico) and this is what I had to do:

Before starting, be sure to check if your phone may already be unlocked by inserting a SIM card from another carrier. If it works, don't continue :)

1. Go to http://www.unlockallcellular.com/
2. Select you brand and model on the left
3. Get your phone's IMEI by going to the phone app and dialing `*#06#`
4. Select your carrier, enter you IMEI and buy the code
5. In a short while (might take a few days max), they will email you your unlock code
6. Put a SIM card from another carrier. An error will pop up and you have the option of entering a code.
7. Enter the unlock code.

If all went well, your phone should be unlocked.